# Where can I find a PHP COM objects library with all their functions?

Tags: php, excel, vba, com

I have been searching everywhere on the internet for certain functions to manipulate an excel COM object with PHP. I am able to create a new excel sheet and save data but I cannot play with styling functions to make the reports look nice.

Here is my code in case it can help in any way :

```
private $users;

private $brdata;

private $excel;

private $book;

private $sheet;

private $today;

private $columns;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->users = $this->model('users');
    $this->brdata = $this->model('brdata');
    $this->excel = new COM("Excel.Application");
    $this->excel->Workbooks->Add();
    $this->book = $this->excel->Workbooks(1);
    $this->sheet = $this->book->Worksheets(1);
    $this->today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 days"));
    $this->columns = array("UPC" => "UPC", "VDR ITEM #" => "CertCode", "BRAND" => "Brand", "ITEM DESCRIPTION" => "ItemDescription", "PACK" => "Pack", "SIZE" => "SizeAlpha", "CASE COST" => "CaseCost", "RETAIL" => "Retail", "ON-HAND" => "onhand", "LAST ORDER" => "lastReceiving", "LAST ORDER DATE" => "lastReceivingDate", "SALES" => "sales", "VDR #" => "VdrNo", "VDR NAME" => "VdrName");;
} 

public function index()
{
    $header = array("A" => "UPC", "B" => "VDR ITEM #", "C" => "BRAND", "D" => "ITEM DESCRIPTION", "E" => "PACK", "F" => "SIZE", "G" => "CASE COST", "H" => "RETAIL", "I" => "ON-HAND", "J" => "LAST ORDER", "K" => "LAST ORDER DATE", "L" => "SALES", "M" => "VDR #", "N" => "VDR NAME");
    $this->setSheetName("Sheet 1");
    $this->setHeader("Example Report", $header);
    $this->setReport('0035', '2016-07-01', '2016-08-01', $header);
    $this->saveReport('example');
}

private function setSheetName($sheetName)
{
    $this->sheet->Name = $sheetName;
}

private function setHeader($title, $header)
{
    $cell = $this->sheet->Range('A1');
    $cell->value = $title; 
    foreach($header as $key => $value)
    {
        $cell = $this->sheet->Range($key . '2');
        $cell->value = $value; 
    }
}

private function setReport($value, $from, $to, $header)
{
    $report = $this->brdata->get_sectionReport($value, $this->today, $from, $to);
    for ($i=3;$i<count($report);$i++)
    {
        foreach($header as $key => $value)
        {
            $cell = $this->sheet->Range($key . $i);
            $cell->value = $report[$i][$this->columns[$value]];
            if($value == "ITEM DESCRIPTION")
            {
                $cell->HorizontalAlignment=-4108;
            }
        } 
    }
}

private function styleReport()
{

}

private function SaveReport($documentName)
{
    $this->book->SaveAs('C:\wamp\documents\\' . $documentName . '.xls');//Enregistrement du document
    $this->sheet = null;//Libération de $sheet
    $this->book = null;//Libération de $book
    $this->excel->Workbooks->Close();//Fermeture du classeur
    $this->excel->Quit();//On quitte Excel
    $this->excel = null;//Libération de l'objet $excel
}
```

}

f I understand correctly, PHP COM objects uses VBA... are the functions similar ?

Thanks for your help !! :-)

Comment: Once you have a reference to the COM object the interfaces are the same as using any other scripting language (such as vbscript for example)  PHP automation via COM doesn't use VBA, although the syntax will be similar so you should be able to find plenty of examples you can translate to PHP.  One big difference is you can't use any of the "built-in" constants which are available within VBA: you will need to provide the numeric values instead.

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking at VBA functions and trying to transate them to PHP. They are in fact similar. I do not need the built in constants, just a little styling for the reports.